# SQL Server : how to populate timeline records based on border values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I was wondering what would be the easiest way to populate records in timeline with last available value from the past - until it changes?

```
 snapshot  val
 ----------------
 201201    NULL
 201202    NULL
 201203    10
 201204    NULL
 201405    NULL
 201406    20
 201407    30
 201408    NULL
 201409    NULL
 201410    NULL
 201411    NULL
 201412    40
 201501    NULL
 ...
```

Expected output then would be:

```
 snapshot  val
 ---------------
 201201    NULL
 201202    NULL
 201203    10
 201204    10
 201405    10
 201406    20
 201407    30
 201408    30
 201409    30
 201410    30
 201411    30
 201412    40
 201501    40
```

Comment: What version of sql server are you using? The answer changed with sql 2012.

Comment: Which version of sql server ?

Comment: I am using sql 2012 guys.

Comment: see this link https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/filling-in-missing-values-using-the-t-sql-window-frame/.  It has simple solutions for all versions.  And in the end it has the usages for Lead and Lag for sql-Sever2012

Comment: @Amir . .. (1) Juan's solution is better than anything in that blog.  (2) The blog doesn't even mention the `outer apply` method, which would be the most natural way of implementing this in SQL Server, regardless of version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2bf8a/9)**

```
SELECT [snapshot],
       [val],
       MAX( [val] ) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY [snapshot]) as [val],
       grp
FROM (                          
      SELECT [snapshot], 
             [val], 
             COUNT([val]) OVER (ORDER BY [snapshot]) grp       
      FROM YourTable
 ) T
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| snapshot |    val |    val | grp |
|----------|--------|--------|-----|
|   201201 | (null) | (null) |   0 |
|   201202 | (null) | (null) |   0 |
|   201203 |     10 |     10 |   1 |
|   201204 | (null) |     10 |   1 |
|   201405 | (null) |     10 |   1 |
|   201406 |     20 |     20 |   2 |
|   201407 |     30 |     30 |   3 |
|   201408 | (null) |     30 |   3 |
|   201409 | (null) |     30 |   3 |
|   201410 | (null) |     30 |   3 |
|   201411 | (null) |     30 |   3 |
|   201412 |     40 |     40 |   4 |
|   201501 | (null) |     40 |   4 |
```